# dnssec-signzone error 'not at top of zone' for a hosted domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec, dns-zone

```
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN yoda.domain2.com.
@   1D    IN SOA yoda.domain2.com.  admin.domain.com. (
                       2015021601         ; Serial yyyymmddnn
                       3h                ; Refresh After 3 hours
                       1h                ; Retry Retry after 1 hour
                       1w                ; Expire after 1 week 1w
                       1h)             ; Minimum negative caching of 1 hour


                               IN NS   yoda.domain2.com.
                               IN NS   r2d2.domain2.com.
domain.com.               IN TXT  v=spf1 mx a:r2d2.domain2.com ~all
domain.com.               MX 0    r2d2.domain2.com.
domain.com.               IN A    108.61.175.20
www.domain.com.           IN A    108.61.175.20
mail.domain.com.          IN A    107.191.60.48
imap.domain.com.          IN A    107.191.60.48
pop.domain.com.           IN A    107.191.60.48
smtp.domain.com.          IN A    107.191.60.48
yoda.domain.com.          IN A    108.61.190.64
r2d2.domain.com.          IN A    107.191.60.48
vader.domain.com          IN A    108.61.175.20
r2d2.domain.com.          IN AAAA 2001:19f0:7000:8945::64
yoda.domain.com.          IN AAAA 2001:19f0:6c00:8141::64

$include /usr/local/etc/namedb/Kdomain.com.zsk.key ; ZSK
$include /usr/local/etc/namedb/Kdomain.com.ksk.key ; KSK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SOA` record is at `yoda.ex-mailer.com` (`$ORIGIN yoda.ex-mailer.com.` redefines the origin to that).

However, the rest of the zone file seems to contain `nyctelecomm.com.` records.
Also, you specify the initial origin to `dnssec-signzone` as `nyctelecomm.com`.

This seems to be a mismatch which will lead to this kind of error. (The `SOA` and `NS` records are supposed to be at the zone apex.)

While the problem with this zone file really isn't DNSSEC related per se, you may want to look into the `auto-dnssec maintain` functionality of modern BIND versions as an alternative to manually signing with `dnssec-signzone`.